# Create a custom style

Tags: android

I'm looking at how to give an app that I develop and deploy it's own look and feel. So I read about the Style and Themes on developer.android.com. After some initial success with text color, text size, background color... I seem to get stuck at changing buttons, toggle buttons... It appears to me that to change the color of a button a .9.png file must be created (possibly for the different dpi's).  Looking at the artwork in the default style, I see a large number of these .9.png files. To have a consistent style they should all be updated.

Is it correct to say that defining a new style involves modifying/recreating the .9.png files?
If no, how should one go about modifying the style of these .9.png based elements?
If so, are there any tools that assist with creating a custom style? And are there any style packages that can be downloaded/purchased?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a good idea to give a new look to every UI control in your application unless you are a very experienced designer. Probably, we can't beat Google designers at their craft and it would be better to comply with existing styles adding some cool features instead of changing button colors at random.

Comment: I agree, changing colors at random is not a good idea. In this case however, I have a style with a blue and white background. The grey buttons and orange text box border are really clashing with the look and feel of the app. I hope this convinces you that I'm not making random changes.

Comment: I didn't mean your style is inferior to the existing ones. I just meant complying to the existing style would make your app more attractive unless your style complies with some other standards such as your company colors or something like that. Sorry I couldn't provide any technical insight.